# Absolutely continuous spectrum invariant under unitary equivalence

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, mathematical-physics, spectral-theory

I am doing an exercise calculating the absolutely continuous spectrum of some operator $A$ by calculating the spectrum of a different operator $B$ unitarily equivalent to $A$, i.e.
$$A = U B U^*.$$
I know that $\sigma (A) = \sigma(B)$ as is easily seen by playing with the resolvent. But I cannot as easily conclude $\sigma_{ac}(A) = \sigma_{ac}(B)$. Am I missing something obvious? How can one show this? I first thought about something along
$$\sigma_{ac}(A) = \sigma(A \mid_{\mathcal H_{ac}}) = \sigma(UBU^* \mid_{\mathcal H_{ac}}) \stackrel{?}{=} \sigma(U B \mid_{\stackrel{\sim}{\mathcal H_{ac}}
}U^*) = \sigma_{ac}(B),$$
but I don't think the third equality is justifiable, especially we have different Hilbert spaces $\mathcal H, \stackrel{\sim}{\mathcal H}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each $h\in H$, you have the corresponding spectral measure $\mu_h^A$. Since 
$$
\langle f(UAU^*)h,h\rangle=\langle f(A)U^*h,U^*h\rangle, 
$$
it follows that $$\mu_h^{UAU^*}=\mu_{U^*h}^A.$$ Replacing $h$ with $Uh$ we get
$$\mu_{Uh}^{UAU^*}=\mu_{h}^A,\ \ h\in H.$$ From this you can deduce that $h\in H_{ac}^A $ if and only if $Uh\in H_{ac}^B$. In other words, $U:H_{ac}^A\to H_{ac}^B$ is an isomorphism. This shows exactly what you want
$$
UAU^*|_{H_{ac}^{UAU^*}}=U(A|_{H_{ac}^A})U^*
$$

Comment: Very clear. Thanks!

Comment: A small question left though: How does one see $f(UAU^*) = Uf(A)U^*$? By checking the properties of the measurable functional calculus?

Comment: Yes. Works for polynomials, and if two Borel measures on a compact subset of $\mathbb C $ agree on polynomials, then they are equal.